# Docker: run binary inside container after build - permission denied

Tags: c++, docker, cmake, docker-compose, dockerfile

The entrypoint of my Dockerfile is:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l", "/runner/run.sh"]
```

The `run.sh` simply builds a binary file and tries to execute the result, like:

```
[....]

cd /tmp/repo
cmake .
make
./main
```

But at the execution of the binary, an error occurs:

```
/runner/run.sh: line 16: ./main: Permission denied
```

I checked the permissions myself by executing the script line by line, and they are sufficient:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 runner runner 660664 Mar  1 17:39 main
```

EDIT:
The docker is wrapped in an `docker-compose`:

```
version: "3.6"
services:

  svrunner:
    image: runner:latest
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp
```

Using `docker run runner:latest` everything works fine, but `docker-compose run svrunner` says permission denied.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Permission denied also happens when the binary isn't linked correctly or doesn't have required libraries. Have you tried building/running `main` in the Docker container manually to see if there are any `ldd` errors?

Comment: Sry, the real problem was the docker-compose tmpfs noexec policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is within docker-compose that mounts tmpfs as (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,...) https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3425.

Using:

```
version: "3.6"
services:

  svrunner:
    image: runner:latest
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp:exec,mode=777
```

solved the problem.